# Poisson Sample Variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, poisson-distribution

$Y_1, ... , Y_n$ are taken from a Poisson distribution. There are two estimators, $\mu_1 = \bar{Y}$ $\mu_2 = Y_1 + Y_2 / 2$.

Show with a mathematical proof that $\mathrm{Var}(\mu_1)$ is less than  $\mathrm{Var}(\mu_2)$.

I am unfamiliar with how to compute the sample variance from a Poisson distribution. It seems intuitive that the larger sample will have the smaller variance, but how do I show this?

Comment: Please add [tag:self-study] tag

Comment: $E(\mu_2) = E(Y_1)+E(Y_2/2) = 1.5E(\mu_1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i Y_i$

and then use that for independent $X,Y$ and constants $a,b$, it follows that

$$Var(aX + bY) = a^2 Var(X) + b^2 Var(Y)$$

The result will be obvious after you write out each variance like this.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am unsure how that rule applies to this particular problem.  If you could explain further that would be great.

Comment: $\bar{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum Y_i = \frac{1}{n} Y_1 + \frac{1}{n}Y_2 + \dots \frac{1}{n}Y_n$... Now apply the rule to get the variance of $\bar{Y}$, then do the same for $\frac{1}{2}(Y_1+Y_2)$ and see which is smaller. Remember that since they are all from the same distribution $Var(Y_i)=\lambda$ is the same for all $i$